# Using the default android image Viewer to show pics

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-gallery

I know that I can open an image using the default android image Viewer, for example with `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)` etc.

If I open the image and then I swipe left/right I'll see the other images saved on the device.

For example, if I open one of whatsapp images, swiping left/right I'll see all other images saved inside whatsapp folder.

Is there a way to pass the default android image Viewer a `List`/`Array` of uri, in order to prevent users from swiping left/right and see all the images on the device?

I want the user to swipe left/right and see only images I allow him to see.

Thank you  in advance

Comment: sorry a bit side tracked, how do you achieve swiping left/ right can see other images? I passed in setDataAndType() with the image path, but cannot see other images in the same folder...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this you can use **[android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)**

> Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data. You supply an implementation of a PagerAdapter to generate the pages that the view shows.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**demo code**

```
ViewPager viewPager;
ArrayList<String> imageArray;
imageArray = new ArrayList<>();
viewPager = findViewById(R.id.cspl_viewPager);
imageArray.add(R.drawable.bg);
imageArray.add(R.drawable.bg);
imageArray.add(R.drawable.bg);
imageArray.add(R.drawable.bg);
imageArray.add(R.drawable.bg);
imageArray.add(R.drawable.bg);
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, imageArray);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

now create `ImageAdapter` like this

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<String> imageArray;

        public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> imageArray) {
            this.context = context;
            this.imageArray = imageArray;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageArray.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.font_size_10);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

//            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this)
                    .load(R.drawable.bg)
                    .into(imageView);


            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

            return imageView;

        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Best scenario is you can use `viewpager` with your image array or image list and you can get the functionality of swipe left or right, Nothing you need to do more just implement `viewpager` and create one adapter to fetch image when getItem event called,

Comment: I see. I've never used viewpager before. I'll study it. Thank you man